# Why does local git merge share the same commit history as a branch but remote pull request does not?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github, git-merge, git-rebase

#### TL;DR

My question is: **how do I get my local git merge behavior to resemble the way it works when I do a pull request from a branch back to main in GitHub, i.e. showing a branched commit history rather than a rebase-like history?**  I don't have it set to automatically do anything with rebase from what I can tell -- see details below.

---

Here's the scenario:

1. The `main` branch is clean.
2. I perform `git checkout -b test-branch`.
3. I make a change to README.md; check in, publish branch to origin.
4. Another change to README.md; check in; repeat two more times (3 total local commits), push to origin.  Here's what git graph shows: 
   [image]
5. Switch to main; merge test-branch from VS code menu:
   [image]
   Then push to origin.  Here's what git graph shows now:
   [image]
   The result looks like a single line of commits **as if it did a rebase (which I don't want)**.
6. Now I repeat steps 1 through 4 creating a new branch `test-branch1`.  Here's what git graph shows:
   [image]
7. Now, instead of merging the branches locally, I perform a pull request from the branch in GitHub:
   [image]
8. Locally, I switch to main and pull from remote.  Here's what git graph now shows:
   [image]
   Now instead of looking like a rebase happened, it has a separate history.

My user gitconfig just has my name and email address, and here is what my repo git config looks like (i.e. no rebase setting from what I can tell):

[image]

So again, my question is *how do I get my local merge behavior to resemble the way it works when I do a pull request from a branch back to main in GitHub, i.e. maintaining the separate commit history from the branch?*

Comment: I will also note that this seems to be specific to just this project/repo.  If I create a fresh test from scratch, it behaves the same locally as it does with a GitHub pull request.  However, I cannot see a difference in configuration that would account for it.

Comment: It's not necessarily that a rebase happened. We can't say as there is no commit on main while you do commits on the test branch. It may be a "fast forward".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--no-ff` flag in git prevents the execution of a "fast-forward" merge and it's the merge method that GitHub uses in pull requests. - [reference](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/about-merge-methods-on-github).

```bash
git merge <branch-name> --no-ff
git pull <remote-name> <branch-name> --no-ff
```

[image]

You might consider `--ff-only` flag as well.

Comment: And this is the default in GitHub I believe. But not locally, at least on OP's computer I believe.

Comment: @GaëlJ indeed.  And armed with this new knowledge, I quickly confirmed that.  https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/about-merge-methods-on-github